# Why can't I turn this string into proper list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
daily_sales = \
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17"""

daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;", ",")

print(daily_sales_replaced)

daily_sales_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")

print(daily_sales_transactions)

daily_transactions_split = []
```

This creates a list with only 1 element containing the whole string but I need to split it up into its transactions. What am I doing wrong?

edit: misspelled daily_transaction_split, added triple quote to end variable

Comment: I'm getting a list of 16 elements. You are missing a `"""` after string declaration.

Comment: You replace `;,;` with `,` which causes you to lose the boundary of a transaction. Replace `;,;` with say `;` and then split on `,`.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing triple-quote `"""`. Please [edit] the question to fix it. See [mre] for reference. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
daily_sales = """Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,;
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,;
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17"""

daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;", ",")

daily_sales_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")

print(daily_sales_transactions)
```

well, I added """ at the end of the daily_sales variable.
checked daily_sales_transactions variables and it has a length of 16,
be sure not to confuse the splitted list with the regular phrase.
I dont think this is really dividing them by transactions though.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the trailing `"""` to the assignment of `daily_sales` like this it works:

```
daily_sales = \
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17"""

daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;", ",")

print(daily_sales_replaced)

daily_sales_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")

print(daily_sales_transactions)

daily_transitions_split = []
```

Note also the corrected spelling of `daily_transions_split`.